# email =null and VerifiedEmail=false google access token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, google-authentication

I am trying to access the token information of google access token in my c sharp web api project.

```
var result = await Client.GetAsync(string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={0}", token.access_token));
string json = await result1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (result1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    GoogleResponse googleResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleResponse>(json1);
    if (googleResponse.Error == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(googleResponse.Email))
    {
    }
}
```

In google response ia always getting email=null and verified_email=false, i am not unserstanding why this happening, actually I need the email id of user who requested the token.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user's email address, you have to request this via scopes before authentication. The user will need to approve this grant.

You will need to add on of these scopes to your authorization request.

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

[Google OAuth2 API, v2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#oauth2v2)

Answer (score 0):

I have few test users and somehow I was getting `null` for few user's email field. After adding `openid` in the console and also in my Google client below I started getting value for email for all users.

```php
    $client->addScope([
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "openid",
    ]);
```